# Which player uses in SharePoint 2013 search results for video preview and how can i find that?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

Can I know which video player is used video preview in the SharePoint 2013 search results?
How can I find out which player is used?
Also the video files types supported out of the box in the search results preview?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 has a built-in HTML5 media player that is used to play all video files that are compatible with the HTML5  implementation for the current browser. If the format is not playable by the HTML5 player, then it uses Silverlight. The video is auto-played when the user opens the video player page. The player streams video content using the BLOB cache, progressive streaming, and bit-rate throttling in the same manner as the SharePoint 2010 media player.

You can find the list of media formats supported by HTML5 in the Wikipedia article [HTML5 video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Supported_video_formats), and the list of media formats supported by Silverlight in the article [Supported media formats, protocols, and log fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080(VS.95).aspx).

Hover over any search result in the organic result list and you’ll see what we named a hover card. It features an actual video player so you can watch or preview the video right then and there.

Check the Official article below:

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2013/03/08/enhanced-video-experience-in-sharepoint-2013/?eu=true